# Accessing parameters from child states of ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In the [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views#what-do-child-states-inherit-from-parent-states) it is said that:

> Child states DO inherit the following from parent states:
>
> Resolved dependencies via resolve
>
> Custom data properties
>
> Nothing else is inherited (no controllers, templates, url, etc).
>   However, children of abstract states do inherit the url property
>   of their parent as a prefix of their own url.

does this mean that in my child state I will have ability to parse whole request string?

**e.g.** If I have the following hierarchy of states:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('contacts', {
    url: 'contacts/:contactId',
    abstract: true,
    /* ... */
  })
  .state('contacts.details', {
    url: '/details',
    controller: 'ContactDetailsController',
    /* ... */
  });
```

Would the injected `$stateParams` in `ContactDetailsController` have access to `contactId` that is meant to be captured in the `contacts` abstract state?

Comment: Did you try it? If so where is working example?

Comment: yes, if your url ends with `contacts/1/details`, you can get the `contactId` using $stateParams in `ContactDetailsController`

Comment: apprently not :( see https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#important-stateparams-gotcha

Answer (score 0):

Found answer in the [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#important-stateparams-gotcha):

## Important $stateParams Gotcha

In state controllers, the `$stateParams` object **will only contain the params that were registered with that state. So you will not see params registered on other states, including ancestors.**

```
$stateProvider.state('contacts.detail', {
   url: '/contacts/:contactId',   
   controller: function($stateParams){
      $stateParams.contactId  //*** Exists! ***//
   }
}).state('contacts.detail.subitem', {
   url: '/item/:itemId', 
   controller: function($stateParams){
      $stateParams.contactId //*** Watch Out! DOESN'T EXIST!! ***//
      $stateParams.itemId //*** Exists! ***//  
   }
})
```

Instead, use a resolve statement in the parent route.

```
$stateProvider.state('contacts.detail', {
   url: '/contacts/:contactId',   
   controller: function($stateParams){
      $stateParams.contactId  //*** Exists! ***//
   },
   resolve:{
      contactId: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
          return $stateParams.contactId;
      }]
   }
}).state('contacts.detail.subitem', {
   url: '/item/:itemId', 
   controller: function($stateParams, contactId){
      contactId //*** Exists! ***//
      $stateParams.itemId //*** Exists! ***//  
   }
})
```